# Is it possible to exit a for..in loop?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to break out of a `for..in` loop?

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
for (const prop in obj) {
    let flag = false
    if (flag === true) break
    if (obj[prop] === 2) { flag = true } else { console.log(obj[prop]) }
}
```

Or is it not possible, as it is with a regular `for` loop?

Comment: the answer is yes, but your logic is wrong.

Comment: move out from for loop your flag declaration and initialization.
With this code you initialize always the flag as false before your check

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` instead of variable

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
for (const prop in obj) {
  if (obj[prop] === 2) {
    break;
  } else {
    console.log(obj[prop])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you need to declare the `flag` *once*, outside the loop, rather than on every iteration inside it:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

let flag = false
for (const prop in obj) {
  if (flag === true) break;
  if (obj[prop] === 2) {
    flag = true
  } else {
    console.log(obj[prop])
  };
}
```

Often, if you want to short-circuit like this, using `.find` or `.some` would be more appropriate, eg:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

const foundKey = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === 2);
console.log(foundKey);
```